# How to generate json from jsp? Not HTML

Tags: json, jsp

I am trying to use jsp to generate json. The problem is, there is generated a HTML which contains my json. The point not to generate html.

[image]
Java7, JBoss4 and jsf probably 2.5.
Thanks

Comment: There is no JSF 2.5. Are you sure you are using Java Server Faces?

Comment: @JasperdeVries I call as JSP or JSF. In fact the code has no JSF features, but it is JSF.

Comment: You might want to use a REST service to serve JSON

Comment: @JasperdeVries thank you, I will take this in consideration. While I am searching the web could you provide any useful sample or resource? As a matter of fact application is not rest and no plans for implementing rest features. So I am not sure yet if it makes sense to make it rest for a single short hardoded json which has its strict flag puprose.

Comment: https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jaxrs.html

Comment: @JasperdeVries thanks, but  it creating new application is definitely not planned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not on the JSP side. Your JSP returns a valid Json, and the browser (Chrome) adds the HTML.

For example, with a JSP containing this source:

```html
<%@ page contentType = "application/json" %>
{"test": {"value": "1", "value2" : "2", "value3" :  "3"}}
```

Google will display:
[image: Json displayed with Chrome]

While Firefox will display:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should set the content type on your JSP:

```
<%@ page contentType = "application/json" %>
```

but the HTML is produced by your code so you  should remove that part.

Comment: It is set, see screenshot, the vi editor and the response headers in browser.